# Can foreign key restrictions be a security benefit and/or risk?

Tags: mysql, sql, security

If, when setting up foreign keys, you set the "delete" restrictions to "cascade" does it create an easier way for attackers to cause more widespread damage to your database?  Contrastingly, does setting your delete restrictions to "restrict" make it more difficult for attackers to cause widespread damage to your database by making it more difficult to delete tables?

Comment: If an attacker manages to gain access to your database either by SQL injection, other bugs or direct, it foreign key restrictions are not really going to make a difference anymore. Consistent data is usually the most important, so using your constraints for that is probably the best

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys and cascading deletions are not meant as defense against attacks. They are purely tools for keeping your database consistent. You should not think of constraints as security related.

As the comment from @Norbert van Nobelen points out, if an attacker already has access to the database to issue delete statements, you should consider all data potentially broken and tampered with.